# Replace lots of single queries for finding last entries with one query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql (8.0.16) table with sensor devices (~1k+ rows) and a table with lots of data (~25M+ rows) from the sensors. There are single indexes on the timestamp and the m2m_device_id columns and a combined one on both columns.

I want to get the last data per device and currently do

```
SELECT * FROM `m2m_datas` WHERE (m2m_device_id = 980) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM `m2m_datas` WHERE (m2m_device_id = 981) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM `m2m_datas` WHERE (m2m_device_id = 982) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
and so on ...
```

This takes between 500ms up to 4s depending on the state of the db.

I though i could improve it by using subqueries or joins to be faster and reduce query count. So i first came up with something like this:

```
SELECT device.name, (
  SELECT timestamp
  FROM m2m_datas 
  WHERE m2m_device_id = device.id 
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 1 ) d 
FROM m2m_devices device;
```

For one this takes even more time (about 10s to 15s) and i dont get all columns out of my data.

After some research i tried the following

```
SELECT device.name, datapoint.timestamp, datapoint.user_data 
FROM m2m_devices device 
INNER JOIN m2m_datas datapoint ON datapoint.id = (
  SELECT d.id FROM m2m_datas AS d WHERE d.m2m_device_id = device.id ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

At least i can get all of my data here if i want but this even took more time (25s to 40s).

When trying around i came up with a slight variant to the above with which i also was able to increase my LIMIT clause if needed

```
SELECT device.name, datapoint.timestamp, datapoint.user_data 
FROM m2m_devices device 
INNER JOIN m2m_datas datapoint ON datapoint.id IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT d.id FROM m2m_datas AS d WHERE d.m2m_device_id = device.id ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
  ) as t
)
```

Interestingly this took less time (10s to 17s).

So im kind of out of ideas of what i could do to increase the performance of the queries. It seems doing single queries for all devices individually is the best option.

Am i missing something here. Are there some better queries which can achieve the same result in at least the same time?

Comment: `last data per device` for all devices, or for specified devices?

Comment: For all devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common approach is as follows. Appropriately indexed, this should be fast enough for most cases...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM m2m_datas x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT m2m_device_id
            , MAX(timestamp) timestamp 
         FROM m2m_datas
        GROUP 
           BY m2m_device_id
     ) y
    ON y.m2m_device_id = x.m2m_device_id
   AND y.timestamp = x.timestamp;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! It works very well for me (results in ms) so im marking it as answer. Would still be nice to see a solution using limit since there might be the need to not only get last but last 3 or last 10 items.

Comment: I wouldn't use limit for that. But I think you could adapt TB's answer without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` might be helpful here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m2m_device_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn
    FROM m2m_datas
    WHERE m2m_device_id IN (980, 981, 982)
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

To further speed up this approach, an index on `(m2m_device_id, timestamp)` might help.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, i have of course an index on (m2m_device_id, timestamp) but unfortunately the cte doesnt seem to be able to use it so the query time is huge.

Comment: The index not being used has nothing to do with the CTE, which is just inlined as SQL code before MySQL runs the query.  It has to do with your data, or maybe a poor choice of query.